# Wrap C++ struct with C++/CLI and use it from C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli, wrapper

I know there are already tons of question similar to this, but i can't solve my problem.

I wrote this little code in Visual C++

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace MyWrapper {
public ref class MySubClass{
        String^ username;
        String^ password;
    };

public enum class MyEnum{
        VALUE1 = 1,
        VALUE2 = 2,
        VALUE3 = 3,
        VALUE4 = 4
    };

public ref class MyClass{
        String^ string1;
        String^ string2;
        String^ string3;
        long exampleNumber;
        MyEnum choosenValue;
        MySubClass credentials;
        unsigned int otherNumber;

    };
}
```

`MyClass` is a struct used in a external dll and i wrote this looking at the dll's source code. It compile and i can see it from my C# code, this C# code works:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
```

but this doesn't work:

```
instance.string1 = "test";
```

it can't find `string1` inside `MyClass`. `string1` is just an example, i can't see any of the values i need. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: string1 is private, so you can't access it from outside.

Comment: I think you probably want to use `property` - [How to: Use Properties in C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f1ec0b1.aspx). You can use the `get` and `set` to forward to your C++ `struct` (although you should name them differently)

Comment: thank you i'm reading it right now! This is the first time i use C++/CLI and i have a lot to learn!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the members of a class are private. You need to declare them to be public.

```
public ref class MyClass 
{
public:
    String^ string1;
    String^ string2;
    String^ string3;
    long exampleNumber;
    MyEnum choosenValue;
    MySubClass credentials;
    unsigned int otherNumber;
};
```

If the structures you are wrapping are pure data containers, then it may be more convenient to use `ref struct` rather than `ref class`. By default, members of a `ref struct` have `public` accessibility.

---

Following on from the comments, you now have problems with `credentials`, which is a `ref class` in your code. Personally I'd be inclined to use `ref struct` for both of these structures. And then it may just be simplest to expose the contained struct using properties:

```
public ref struct MySubClass
{
    String^ username;
};

public ref struct MyClass 
{
private:
    MySubClass credentials;
public:
    property String^ username {
        String^ get()
        {
            return credentials.username;
        }
        void set(String^ value)
        {
            credentials.username = value;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: wow it works, i feel pretty dumb now. thank you, i will mark this as answer in 5 minutes :)

Comment: just another thing: i can't set instance.credentials from C# code, it says its "read only"! I just declared a MySubClass object and assigned to instance.credentials

Comment: just did it (both MyClass and MySubClass are now ref struct) but still same error :( When reading MyClass metadata from C# looks like MySubClass is the only one marked as readonly